# RestKit - Not key-value coding compliant, no root in JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit, key-value-coding

I've been trying to map the following object from the JSON response and from everything I see in the console output, there isn't any reason why the mapping isn't successful - I appreciate if anyone could have a check and see:

```
@interface RKElectionsModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) bool isActive;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *electionID;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *summary;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *availableSeats;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *candidatesCount;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *withdrawnCount;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSSet *candidates;

@end

/**
 * Election Detail Mapping: Getting all election details, we have some extra information from
 * the API call
 *
*/
RKObjectMapping *electionDetailsMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKElectionsModel class]];

// Map JSON -> entities
[electionDetailsMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"id": @"electionID",
     @"title": @"title",
     @"summary": @"summary",
     @"active": @"isActive",
     @"availableSeats": @"availableSeats",
     @"candidatesCount": @"candidatesCount",
     @"withdrawnCount": @"withdrawnCount"
 }];

// Register our mappings with the provider
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:electionDetailsMapping pathPattern:@"/api/elections/:electionID/all" keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

[Console output](http://pastebin.com/hE3cAZ0e) on pastebin and any examples of the JSON response you can visit [here](http://stv.lewistheobald.com/api/elections/1/all)

Appreciate any help,
Lewis

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your trying to map a NSString to NSNumber.

In your `NSObject` try to add the following validation and transform the string you receive from the server to a NSNumber when the mapping starts.

```
- (BOOL)validateAvailableSeats:(id *)ioValue error:(NSError **)outError {
       // Force the value to be a NSNumber
       *ioValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[(NSString*)value doubleValue] ]
       return YES;
}
```

In the [RestKit Wiki](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping#type-transformation) you'll find more transformations for your values.